# How to use a specific variable out of three returned variables?

Tags: javascript

I have got three variables (x,y,z) and I have returned them all. I want to use a specific variable out of the three instead of just using the newest one.

This is to test what I can do for my loading screen which I mentioned in a previous question. I have tried to put the variable in the void to no avail. I have researched this and I haven't found anything.

```
function inputs(){
    var x = 19;
    var y = 20;
    var z = 21;
    return x, y, z;
}

function output(){
    console.log(inputs(x));
}

output();
```

My expected result is that I can log x to my console. My actual result is that it says undefined.

Comment: try returning an array of your values. This won't work

Comment: which one would you like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input(x)` here `x` is undefined so.

And **x,y,z** will also always return `z`. Read more about [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

So what you're trying to achieve can be done like this with object.

**You can do it like this**

```js
function inputs(input){
    let obj =
    { x : 19,
      y : 20,
      z : 21 }
    return obj[input]
}

function output(){
    console.log(inputs('x'));
}

output();
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can do this:

```js
function inputs() {
    var x = 19;
    var y = 20;
    var z = 21;
    return {x, y, z};
}

function output() {
    console.log(inputs().x);
}

output();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `x, y, z` actually [only returns `z`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). What you want is an Object, like `let a = {x, y, z}`, which you can then access z from using `a.z`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return comma separated values like this:

```
return x, y, z;
```

Instead what you can do is return an object:

```
function inputs(){
    var x = 19;
    var y = 20;
    var z = 21;
    return {x: x, y: y, z: z};
}

function output(){
   console.log(inputs().x)
}

output()
```

Hope you understand.